# Folder Link of the uploaded file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Here is my situation

I am developing a project management application in `asp.net`.

In that when a customer gives the project detail to the employee, he also uploads a  file with that (~ 100 mb).

I don't want that to be uploaded by the customer.

We have all the drives connected in a local network.

What I'm thinking is instead of uploading a file he can give the link to the folder location and by clicking on that link in the browser itself the employee would be able to access the file.

How should I implement this OR please suggest some good practice or method to solve this type of a problem.

Comment: Is this site running on the local Intranet?

Comment: Yes.It is completely intranet based

Comment: Then the speed will be a lot faster, I think it would be interesting if you did a small prototype and uploaded 100MB file, how long it would take. I would also suggest that if its like a word document or something with text that you zip that file, there are asp.net zip tools which would make that file a lot smaller.

Comment: then the end user also have to download the file.anyway the file is already there on drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's all intranet, you could just have the user provide you a UNC path that the ASP.Net Application Pool identity has access to.

In order to provide the file back to the user, you can either provide the UNC path as an href such as:

```
<a href="file://///server/path/to/file.txt"/>
```

Or write the file to the response:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer= true;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","inline;filename=file.txt");
Response.Charset = "";
```

Comment: and how to get the UNC path as a input from the user

Comment: just a basic html form with a text input would be fine

Comment: i'm not sure will he be able to access the UNC path through the browser.beacuse the user has a domain account( not local)

Comment: as long as both the apppool account and the user account have access to the share, it will work.